# ¿Cómo gestiono operaciones aritméticas con números complejos en Python?

Tags: python, split, números-complejos

Tengo que sumar 2 numeros complejos tipo (-5+17i)+(13-15i) = 8+2i ya que se suman por separados terminos existentes y imaginarios.

La cuestión es que lo recupero como texto y uso un split para poder recuperar números existentes como el -5 y el 13 y también los imaginarios como el +17i y el -15i, para poder sumarlos de manera respectiva.

Pero el split no me permite separarlos antes de un operador matemático, lo máximo que pude hacer fue que al recuperar los números complejos que separara los términos usando una coma tipo (-5,+17i), así si me sale el ejercicio pero la idea que que solo recuperando el numero tal como esta por ejemplo -18+5i funcione pero como les menciono no encuentro ni en internet una forma de separar antes de un operador matemático, maso menos así esta mi código:

```
#Calcular la suma de 2 números complejos

#Leer valor del primer número complejo

NCom1 = str(input("Ingrese el primero numero complejo: "))

#Leer valor del segundo número complejo

NCom2 = str(input("Ingrese el segundo numero complejo: "))

#Separar términos del primero número complejo
        
D = NCom1.split(",")

#Guardar términos separados

E1 = int(D [0])
D = D[1].split("i")
I1 = int(D [0])

#Separar términos del segundo número complejo

D = NCom2.split(",")

#Guardar términos separados

E2 = int(D [0])
D = D[1].split("i")
I2 = int(D [0])

#Hallar la suma

Suma = str(E1+E2) + "," + str(I1+I2) +"i"

#Escribir Suma

print(Suma)
```

Comment: Si entiendo bien, quieres hacer un split con el `'+'`, pero usas `','` y no te sale. Prueba con `'+'`. De todos modos, python tiene `complex` como tipo de dato nativo. No es necesario separar los elementos y pasarlos a enteros. Basta con `complex(NCom1) + complex(NCom2)`.

Comment: Un título es diferente de la descripción.

Comment: @fredyfx. Quiere sumar números complejos, pero su dificultad está en parsearlos, no en la operación de suma misma. Quedaría mejor si redujera la pregunta al puro problema de como parsear la entrada.

Answer (score 1):

No es tan fácil hacer un split de ese tipo porque hay que identificar el caracter de división (+, -) y si es que existe, puesto que un valor real (por ejemplo, 12) también es complejo.

Esta función primero elimina los parentesis de los extremos, si es que los tiene.
Luego con un `for` recorre caracter por caracter y lo va acumulando en una variable `value`. Cuando encuentra un caracter `+` o `-` es porque ha encontrado la división entre real e imaginario, entonces lo que se lleva acumulado en `value` se agrega a la lista `result` y se reinicia la variable `value` con el valor de `i`. Después de salir del `for` hay que agregar lo que se llevaba acumulando en `value` hasta ese momento.

En este punto `result` puede tener desde 1 a `n` elementos, por consiguiente ahora se va a evaluar si esos elementos cumplen con ser números complejos correctos. Si la lista tiene más de dos elementos (`else`), es porque se introdujo algo como `3+4+7i`, que está incorrecto. En ese caso se puso `real = 'x'` para que falle cuando se evalúa en el bloque `try`.

Finalmente un `try - except` evalua cada componente real o imaginario. Si no falla ninguno, se asigna a la variable `to_result`, y se cambia la condición del `while` para que ya no se cumple más y se retorna

```
def i_to_num(cplx):
    if cplx in ['i', '+i']:
        imag = '1'
    elif cplx == '-i':
        imag = '-1'
    else:
        imag = cplx[:-1]
    return imag

def get_complex(msg):
    valid_cplx = False
    while not valid_cplx:
        c = input(msg)
        if len(c) == 0:
            continue
        c = c[1:] if c[0] == '(' else c
        c = c[:-1] if c[-1] == ')' else c
        result = []
        value = c[0]
        for i in range(1, len(c)):
            if c[i] in ['+', '-']:
                result.append(value)
                value = c[i]
            else:
                value += c[i]
        result.append(value)
        real = '0'
        imag = '0'
        if len(result) == 1:
            if result[0][-1] == 'i':
                imag = i_to_num(result[0])
            else:
                real = result[0]
        elif len(result) == 2:
            real = result[0]
            imag = i_to_num(result[1])
        else:
            real = 'x' # Hacer fallar el [try]
        
        try:
            to_return = (int(real), int(imag))
            valid_cplx = True
        except:
            print("Error, no es un complejo bien formado")
    return to_return
```

Pruebas:

```
print(get_complex("Escribe un numero complejo: "))
# (12+3i) -> (12, 3)
# 12-3i   -> (12, -3)
# 12      -> (12, 0)
# -23i    -> (0, -23)
# 0       -> (0, 0)
# i       -> (0, 1)
# (-i)    -> (0, -1)
# 1+i     -> (1, 1)
# 1+2     -> Error, no es un complejo bien formado
# asd     -> Error, no es un complejo bien formado
# 1+2i+3  -> Error, no es un complejo bien formado
```

Ya con eso puedes seguir tu código, le pides ambos números complejos a la función y luego se suman las partes reales y las partes imaginarias de cada variable.

```
a = get_complex("Primer complejo: ")
b = get_complex("Segundo complejo: ")
sum_real = a[0] + b[0]
sum_imag = a[1] + b[1]
.
.
.
```

Comment: interesante respuesta, ¿pero no crees que podrías utilizar `complex` para gestionar estos números?

Answer (score 0):

La forma optima de separar las partes real e imaginaria es usando expresiones regulares, pero eso es demasiado complicado.

En lugar de eso, aprovecharemos la siguiente caracteristica de los números complejos: la separación es un signo "+" o "-" a continuaciòn de un valor numérico.

Para simplificar, asumiremos solo partes enteras, o sea, sin decimales ni exponentes.

La funciòn `split()` no sirve para el propósito buscado. En su lugar, vamos a usar la función `find(valor, inicio)` para buscar la primera ocurrencia de "+" o "-" a partir de la tercera posición en el string numérico.

La función `find()` retorna el indice donde encuentra el valor, o -1 si no lo encuentra.

Buscaremos ambos simbolos "+" y "-" y eligiremos el primero de ellos para separar el numero en sus partes.

Ejemplo:

```
lista = [" ( 5 + 7j )", "( 5 - 7j)", "(+5+7j)",  "(+5 - 7j)", "(-5+7j)", "(-5-7j)", "(+5-7j)"]


for complejo in lista:
    # Eliminamos los espacios del numero para simplificar lo que viene.
    normal = complejo.replace(" ", "")

    # Buscamos ambas operaciones.
    operador_plus = normal.find("+", 2)
    operador_minus = normal.find("-", 2)
    
    # Ahora determinamos cual operación está primero.
    if operador_plus >= 0 and operador_minus >= 0:
        operador = min(operador_plus, operador_minus)
    elif operador_plus >= 0:
        operador = operador_plus
    else:
        operador = operador_minus

    # Extraemos la operacion.
    operacion = normal[operador]

    # Extraemos la parte real
    real = normal[1:operador]

    # Y la parte imaginaria
    imag = normal[operador+1:-1]

    print("%s, real=%s, imag=%s, operacion=%s" % (normal, real, imag, operacion))
```

produce

```
(5+7j), real=5, imag=7j, operacion=+
(5-7j), real=5, imag=7j, operacion=-
(+5+7j), real=+5, imag=7j, operacion=+
(+5-7j), real=+5, imag=7j, operacion=-
(-5+7j), real=-5, imag=7j, operacion=+
(-5-7j), real=-5, imag=7j, operacion=-
(+5-7j), real=+5, imag=7j, operacion=-
```

**Edit:**

Revisemos la fortaleza de esta propuesta usando un conjunto de casos más diversos, patológicos talvez.

Con está lista:

```
lista = ["(344+5i)", "(3+543i)", "(-3+543i)", "(+3.45 - +100.34j)", "(-1000-+.3j)", "(14.300 - 0j)"]
```

obtengo estos resultados:

```
(344+5i), real=344, imag=5i, operacion=+
(3+543i), real=3, imag=543i, operacion=+
(-3+543i), real=-3, imag=543i, operacion=+
(+3.45-+100.34j), real=+3.45, imag=+100.34j, operacion=-
(-1000-+.3j), real=-1000, imag=+.3j, operacion=-
(14.300-0j), real=14.300, imag=0j, operacion=-
```

Acostumbrate a programar con cuidado tus algoritmos y a probar con despiadado rigor tus resultados.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [como escribir una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), para que te informes de la manera adecuada de responder una pregunta. Saludos!

Comment: @gcoronel99 sería bueno ser más específico en la crítica (y menos rápido en el voto negativo)

Comment: @gcoronel99 en que punto piensas que esta respuesta no es una buena respuesta? por favor, moderemos los comentarios y el lenguaje.